# Can I add a React input event handler only on certain conditions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I want to add the `onFocus` event handler on my element only if a condition is true. Right now, I was hoping to be able to do a ternary on the `onFocus` itself, so something like this:

```
<input
  type='text'
  className='some-class'
  value={value}
  onFocus={useTheOnFocus ? evt => onFocusHandler(evt) : null}
  onChange={evt => onChangeHandler(evt.target.value)}
/>
```

This however, does not work and generates a series of errors and warnings:

> Uncaught TypeError: handler.apply is not a function
>
> Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

I know the alternative would be to just write the input tag twice within it's own ternary one with the `onFocus` and the other without it. But I would like to do it in a more condensed matter. Is there another simpler and more condensed way to get this done?

Comment: Instead of `null` just use `() => {}`?

Comment: Oops! I had completely forgotten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add this

```
onFocus={useTheOnFocus ? onFocusHandler : undefined}
```

or set a handler

```
onFocus={onFocusHandler}
```

and check a condition in a handler

```
onFocusHandler = (ev) => {
   if(!condition) {
      return null;
   }
   // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give event handlers a value of `undefined` if you don't want them to be active.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { useTheOnFocus: false };

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        useTheOnFocus: !prevState.useTheOnFocus
      }));
    }, 2000);
  }

  onFocusHandler = evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log("Focus handler active");
  };

  render() {
    const { useTheOnFocus } = this.state;

    return (
      <input
        type="text"
        className="some-class"
        onFocus={useTheOnFocus ? this.onFocusHandler : undefined}
      />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```